# When can I use my lights again after a ceiling leak

Tags: electrical, plumbing, water-damage

We had a leak from a second floor sink that went under the baseboards and dripped through a recessed light fixture on the first floor ceiling. It wasn't much water. Only a few oz made it through. I've pulled out the light trim to help it dry (and of course turned off the floor water above).

My question is, when is it safe to use the light fixture again? I currently have the circuit switched off at the wall.

[image]

Comment: It's about 10:40 (based on the clock on the wall), and it's light outside. If you're in the northern hemisphere, it's winter time and humidity should be pretty low, so it should dry more quickly. If you're in the southern hemisphere, it could still be light outside at 22:40, so it could be summer and, likely, more humid, so it'll dry more slowly. All in all, it depends.

Comment: Nobody can answer that, it will depend on how long it takes too dry. But the circuit breaker will tell you if it is ready or not. So just turn it on. If you had GFCI breakers those will tell you.

Answer (score 3):

Should be safe when it is dry and has no moisture in it.

Too many factors to tell how long it would take.

Would turn off the breaker for that light and remove from the ceiling so you can turn it upside down to drain any water that got inside.  Having a small fan blowing on it will help.  Depending on how much water drains out, maybe a few hours to dry completely.

Comment: If you want to be double-sure, I would replace the fixture. This looks like an LED-retrofit fixture, which can be bought at one of the box stores for less than $20.

Answer (score 1):

With the switch off, feel around the fixture and along the edge of the drywall. wipe it with a paper towel so you can see if any moisture collects on it. If you find it is all dry, wait 24 hrs to be sure and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be an LED retrofit for a traditional recessed can light. The driver electronics for it would all be in the black plastic cylinder of the unit. It's very unlikely that these had any exposure to water; even if the leak from above caused water to fall onto the top of the can light housing, and then the water ran through a hole or gap in the housing, and finally dripped onto the housing for the LED driver the chances that water got inside are still quite low.

If the evidence shows that the metal housing near the drywall edge and the white plastic around the LED lamp are the only parts that got wet then it should be fine to use immediately. If not, simply disconnect the LED lamp from the can housing and set it aside to dry for a day. Go ahead and operate the other lights on the circuit normally.